# UICollectionViewCell unwanted animation during UICollectionView scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm having a strange cell animation behaviour during the UICollection view scroll.
I have created a custom cell with a fixed size(300,200) in the storyboard. 
In runtime I'm changing the cell size into (360,200) using: `collectionView:collectionViewLayout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath.`

In iOS7 during the scroll new cells will be animated from 300 to 360.
iOS6 doesn't animate.

The layout is UICollectionViewFlowLayout.
I have tried to `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. didn't helped.

How can I avoid this animation?
Thanks.